# Hover detail setting

Tags: configuration

I need help to create question mark icon(tooltip) just beside the field.
I tried using mini pagelayout link in edit layout,it did not worked.

Kindly help.

Comment: where did you want to show this icon?

Comment: in the record detail page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a field tool-tip like that on standard fields by populating the Help text, which is part of the field definition rather than the page layout. For custom objects, this is under Setup->Create->Custom Objects->(object name), and for standard objects you'll find the field list under Customize->Object Name.